# Xcode: Twitter text field post issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, twitter, uitextfield

I've come across a strange problem. If I run the following code, I get my Tweet box text as "Today I have listened to (null)". And when I changed str1 in the [tweet setInitialText:str1]; to txt1.text the code won't run and I get this message "Too many arguments to method call expected 1 have 2".

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize txt1;

-(IBAction)Twitte{

    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]){

        NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Today I have listened to %@", txt1.text];

        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [tweet setInitialText:str1];
        [tweet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/#!/"]];

        [self presentModalViewController:tweet animated:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IBAction expects an id param.  The null in the string means that the txt1 is nil.  It can't answer a string because it doesn't point to anything.  Add a param and check where you initialize txt1.

Comment: Thank you for your respond as you mentioned I added a parameter and I found my problem. Thanks again.